# Portmanteau Theorem in Multiple Dimensions

Tags: probability, statistics, weak-convergence

I have a significant issue in trying to prove the claim highlighted in red (see picture below), which is in Van der Vaart's "Asymptotic Statistics" text, where we assume $X_n = (X_{n,1}, ..., X_{n,d})^T $ and $X = (X_1, ..., X_d)^T$ are both in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $P(X\le x) = P(X_1 \leq x_1, ..., X_d \leq x_d)$ - elementwise vector inequalities.

Let $a = (a_1, ..., a_d)^T$ and $b = (b_1, ..., b_d)^T$ be in the set of continuity points for $P(X \leq x)$ with $a_i < b_i \forall i$.

$I = \prod_{i=1}^d (a_i, b_i]$ in this case.

If $d=1$, the claim is trivial (as $P(X_n \in I) = P(X_n \leq b_1) - P(X_n \leq a_1)$ which converges to the required quantity by assumption), but for $d > 1$, I am completely lost.

My attempt at proving it is as follows:

$ P(X_n \in I) = P(X_n \leq b, X_n > a)$

$= P(X_n \leq b) - P(X_n \leq b \cap (\cup_{i=1}^d \{X_{n,i} \leq a_i\}))$

$= P(X_n \leq b) - P(\cup_{i=1}^d \cap_{j=1}^d \{X_{n,j} \leq b_j \} \cap \{X_{n,i} \leq a_i\})$

$= P(X_n \leq b) - P(\cup_{i=1}^d \{X_{n,i} \leq a_i \} \cap_{j \ne i} \{X_{n,j} \leq b_j \} )$

(this is all just applying definitions)

Obviously the first term converges to $P(X \leq b)$ but I have no clue how to show that the second term converges to $P(\cup_{i=1}^d \{X_{i} \leq a_i \} \cap_{j \ne i} \{X_{j} \leq b_j \} )$

Can anyone offer any help?

[image: Portmanteau Lemma]

Answer (score 0):

If $I=(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}]$ denotes a multidimensional interval with lower endpoint $\mathbf{a}=(a_1,\dots,a_d)$ and upper endpoint $\mathbf{b}=(b_1,\dots,b_d)$, then $P(\mathbf{X}\in I)$ for $\mathbf{X}\sim F$ is the so-called $F$-volume of $I$, given by $$\Delta_{(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}]}F = \sum_{\mathbf{i}\in\{0,1\}^d}(-1)^{i_1+\dots+i_d}F(a_1^{i_1}b_1^{1-i_1},\dots,a_d^{i_d}b_d^{1-i_d}).$$ For $d=1$, this is $P(X\in(a,b])=F(b)-F(a)$, for $d=2$ the well-known $P(\mathbf{X}\in(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}])=F(b_1,b_1)-F(b_1,a_2)-F(a_1,b_2)+F(a_1,a_2)$ results.

Clearly, $\Delta_{(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}]}F$ is a sum with $2^d$ summands depending on $F$. So if $F_n$ (the distribution function of $X_n$) converges to $F$, then $\Delta_{(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}]}F_n$ converges to $\Delta_{(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}]}F$, as long as $\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}$ are continuity points of $F$ (van der Vaart first assumes $F$ to be continuous everywhere and then provides an argument why one can always choose continuity points of $F$).

For intervals of different forms, one obtains the volume via the corresponding one-sided limits. E.g. for $d=2$ and $[\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}]$ one has $P(\mathbf{X}\in[\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}])=F(b_1,b_1)-F(b_1,a_2-)-F(a_1-,b_2)+F(a_1-,a_2-)$.